# Spring Boot - Handling NoHandlerFoundException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Read the [Spring Reference Guide on how to handle NoHandlerFoundException](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-servlet-sequence) and found that Spring sets, by default, `throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound` to `false`.

Knowing that, I thought it was a good idea to set this parameter to `true`.

I'm using Spring Boot.

Did so:

**MyConfig.java**

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MyConfig {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(MyConfig.class, args);
        context.getBean(DispatcherServlet.class).setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);

        // ...
    }
}
```

Alright, now `throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound` is equals `true`. However, that didn't worked as expected. The `DispatcherServlet` continued not throwing the `NoHandlerFoundException`. This way, I was unable to handle it.

**CustomExceptionHandler.java** *(this didn't worked)*

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler;

@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity <Object> handleNoHandlerFoundException(NoHandlerFoundException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        // do my own handle ...

        // then, return ...
    }

}
```

After a bit of search, found that adding `@EnableWebMvc` should work. Then, I did add this annotation to my `CustomExceptionHandler`

**CustomExceptionHandler.java** *(this did worked)*

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler;

@EnableWebMvc
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity <Object> handleNoHandlerFoundException(NoHandlerFoundException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        // do my own handle ...

        // then, return ...
    }

}
```

This way, the handle works. However, I'm using Spring Boot. The Spring Boot docs suggests that if I insert `@EnableWebMvc`, I would lose some Spring Boot MVC Auto-configuration features, since I would take complete controll of Spring MVC. ([See here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-auto-configuration)).

> "If you want to take complete control of Spring MVC, you can add your own @Configuration annotated with @EnableWebMvc."

Would I lose Spring MVC Auto-configuration? I mean, the `@EnableWebMvc`, in my case, it's not in a `@Configuration` class.

My question is based on the fact that I'm not sure how this code above works, and I want to know if there's another way of doing this without losing the Spring MVC Auto-configuration. Could someone explain?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Spring Boot auto-configuration will automatically add a `ResourceHttpRequestHandler` to deal with serving static resource. By default this handler is mapped against `/**` and is the last item in the handler chain.

What this means is the `DispatcherServlet` won't throw a `NoHandlerFoundException` because it found the resource handler. The resource handler processes the request and calls [`response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND)`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/d8ef6b7c748fbb0a61b4996dc4e3a4dfb1fe1c41/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/resource/ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java#L454) to return a 404.

If you don't want this behavior, you can add the following to your `application.properties`:

```
spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
spring.resources.add-mappings=false
```

The will configure the dispatcher servlet to throw the exception *and* also tell Spring Boot not to register the resource handler.

Before you go too far down that route, you might want to look at [this section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-error-handling) of the reference docs to see if it wouldn't be better to handle those errors in a different way. It's not totally clear from your question what you're actually trying to do in your error handler, but if it's just dealing with 404s then there's probably a better way.

Comment: Thank you, Phil. With Spring Boot 2.3, inclusion of those properties doesn't have any effect. For instance, after implementing `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler#handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported`, the `DispatcherServlet` sends request with unsupported HTTP Method to `/error` rather than this handler. The issue is, `ErrorController` is container wide, so if I have multiple controllers where each require to send different JSON messages upon errors (specific for those controllers), then I'm in a bind, and have to resort to forwarded URI examination. Is there a reason why Spring behaves like this?

Comment: In new version of Spring `spring.resources.add-mappings` was relpaced with `spring.web.resources.add-mappings`.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Date;


import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;

import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler;


@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionController extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ExceptionController.class.getName());

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleAllExceptions(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
        ExceptionResponse exceptionResponse = new ExceptionResponse(new Date(), ex.getMessage(),
                request.getDescription(false));
        return new ResponseEntity(exceptionResponse, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity <Object> handleNoHandlerFoundException(NoHandlerFoundException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        ExceptionResponse exceptionResponse = new ExceptionResponse(new Date(), ex.getMessage(),
                request.getDescription(false));
        
            logger.error(request);
        return new ResponseEntity(exceptionResponse, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
```

Comment: I don't see how this helps, if NoHandlerFoundException is never thrown.