# Spring - What's the effect of using @EnableWebMvc without @Configuration annotation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In Spring, what would happen if instead of using `@EnableWebMvc` with `@Configuration` use only `@EnableWebMvc`, like the example below?

With `@Configuration`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class Clazz {
    // ..
}
```

Without `@Configuration`

```
@EnableWebMvc
public class Clazz {
    // ..
}
```

Comment: Do it, and you'll see.

Comment: @JBNizet the main reason I'm asking it, is because of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51048707/spring-boot-handling-nohandlerfoundexception)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@EnableWebMvc` on its own, cannot do much unless it is discovered by Spring. Spring searches for classes marked `@Component`. `@Configuration` is marked with `@Component` and therfore all classes marked with `@Configuration` are discovered by Spring component scan same way as ones marked with `@Component`. `@EnableWebMvc` marked classes are discovered only if they are marked with `@Component` or any annotation that is marked `@Component`